# Python - program keeps iterating over deleted files

Tags: python

I've written a program that iterates over all CSV files in a directory and creates a new CSV file based on their contents.

I've written a function ('summary()') that performs these tasks and is called by the following code

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
csv_list = []

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(cwd):
    for f in filenames:
       if f.endswith('.csv'):
            csv_list.append(f)

#for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(cwd):
summary(csv_list)
```

Once the file has been loaded into the function, its added to a pandas DF by the following code

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=True, sep=';') for f in files))
```

The function creates a output csvfile called 'combined_csv'. 
I delete this file between each run (as I currently testing the program).

However I keep running into the following peculiar bug.

```
FileNotFoundError: File 'combined.csv' does not exist
```

Even though I deleted the file, the program still parses over it - (where it crashes when it tries to load). Why though? I restart the program after deleting the file, the file should not appear in the 'csv_list' variable at all.

Is the information cached somehow?

I've added the full traceback below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "summary.py", line 112, in <module>
    summary(csv_list)
  File "summary.py", line 17, in summary
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=True, sep=';') for f in files))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 206, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 236, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
  File "summary.py", line 17, in <genexpr>
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=True, sep=';') for f in files))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 405, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 394, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:4209)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 710, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:8873)
FileNotFoundError: File b'combined.csv' does not exist
```

*Edit* I've simplified the program (the code wasnt relevant to the problem, and changed the code to this. This is *all* of the code that is run.

I am executing the program from a terminal (Ubuntu 16.04), located in the directory.

```
$ pwd
```

returns

```
/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/AHP_Scanner/PVM/true_run/testsum

$ ls -a /home/jasper/PycharmProjects/AHP_Scanner/PVM/true_run/testsum
```

returns:

```
    .            fixed_10.csv  fixed_13.csv  fixed_16.csv  fixed_19.csv  fixed_21.csv  fixed_4.csv  fixed_7.csv  goed
..           fixed_11.csv  fixed_14.csv  fixed_17.csv  fixed_1.csv   fixed_2.csv   fixed_5.csv  fixed_8.csv  summary.py
fixed_0.csv  fixed_12.csv  fixed_15.csv  fixed_18.csv  fixed_20.csv  fixed_3.csv   fixed_6.csv  fixed_9.csv
```

As we can see, the file 'combined_csv' does not exist

Yet when I run the following code:  (this is all of the code that is run, the rest of summary.py has been commented out)

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
csv_list = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(cwd):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            print(f)
```

I get this response:

```
fixed_8.csv
fixed_10.csv
fixed_4.csv
fixed_11.csv
fixed_9.csv
fixed_7.csv
fixed_0.csv
fixed_12.csv
fixed_2.csv
fixed_5.csv
fixed_20.csv
fixed_18.csv
fixed_14.csv
fixed_6.csv
fixed_15.csv
fixed_3.csv
fixed_1.csv
fixed_17.csv
fixed_13.csv
fixed_19.csv
fixed_16.csv
fixed_21.csv
combined.csv
```

I am at a loss why this file keeps appearing.

Comment: What are you running the program with? An IDE? Notebook? Command-line?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't preserving path information?

Comment: The two parts of your program do not seem to match: one generates a list of files called `csv_list`, the other reads from a list of files called `files`.

Comment: Change `csv_list.append(f)` to `csv_list.append(os.path.join(root, f))`. Some of the files you are adding to the `csv_list` container are not in the current directory; therefore they can't be found without a correct path.

Comment: Also, please share the definition of `summary`. It looks like that's where the error occurs.

Comment: Do you *create* `csv_list` anew every time? Seems `'combined.csv'` is getting into `csv_list` even though you deleted it.  You probably haven't posted enough info. Can you make a (toy) [mcve] that illustrates your problem?  What steps have you taken to debug this- so we don't duplicate your efforts?

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone! I've updated my original question to some of your suggestions. Rather than including the entire codebase, I've commented everything out and reduced the file to +/- 5 lines. 

The problem still occurs, but this should be easier to debug.

Comment: What's `goed` in the file listing? Is it a folder and does it contain anything?

Comment: Is `goed` file or directory? If the latter, maybe it contains another file 'combined.csv'?

Comment: `os.walk` scans through all directories even subdirectories. Your `ls` shows a *goed* folder (assumed since there is no extension). See if *combined.csv* is not there or in yet other child folders.

Comment: That was it! Gosh, I knew I was missing something. Thanks!

Comment: You could change to `for filenames in os.listdir('path/'):`